# Using SwiftUI, how to force multi-line text field on Mac app?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I'm trying to force a minimum number of lines (5) in my SwiftUI text field, but instead it shows only a single line at a time whether I start with more text or add more lines...

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Title String", text: $viewModel.currentTitle)
        TextField("Text Template", text: $viewModel.currentCode, axis: .vertical)
            .lineLimit(5, reservesSpace: true)
    }
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .padding()
}
```

Comment: `reservesSpace: true` which you already have should allow you to show more than one line. And I cannot reproduce your issue on playground, it shows multiple lines. Unless you are talking about ability to specify multiple lines, in which case use `TextEditor`.

Comment: Not sure why on Mac app, this code is only showing one line worth of space (it scrolls when I add more), but TextEditor works fine and didn't know about it. Thanks.